# DataGridView Yes No ComboBox Column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have what on the face of it seems a pretty simple requirement, I need an unbound combobox column to hold an option list of 'Yes' and 'No'.  In combobox parlance Yes and No are the DisplayMembers corresponding to ValueMembers 1 and 0 respectively which in turn are the values held in the field of the database table.  I use bound combobox columns in the application extensively and am very familiar with building them, but can't for the hell of me work out how to incorporate this simple list functionality in the datagridview application.  Could somebody please put me out of my misery with some sample code.

Thanks for your feedback Plutonix.  The DGV is bound to an underlying table. Hopefully, the following code should give you some idea of what I am attempting to acheive.  The code specifically relevant to this post is in the call to PopulateUnboundComboBox(comboBoxCol, {"Yes", "No"}).

```
Private Sub GetData()
    Const procName As String = "GetData()"

    Dim myValue As String = ""
    Dim myDataSource As Integer = 0

    Try

        'First clear the existing grid
        With Me.uxGrid
            If .ColumnCount > 0 Then
                'clear the grid
                ClearGrid(Me.uxGrid)
            End If
        End With

        _Logger.SendLog(Me.Name & "." & procName & " - Fetching device data.", NLog.LogLevel.Trace)

       'Get the data from the database
        If Not _dataSourceID = 0 Then
            _sqlStatement = "SELECT ID, TEXT, CATEGORY, MOUNTING, DATASOURCEID, TANALYSIS" & _
                              " FROM P_TBL_DEVICE WHERE DATASOURCEID = " & _dataSourceID
            _criteria = "WHERE DATASOURCEID = " & _dataSourceID
        Else
            _sqlStatement = ""
            _criteria = ""
        End If

        _myDeviceMngr = New DeviceManager(_currentDB, _userName, _myPwd)

        'Now get the latest data
        _myDataSet = _myDeviceMngr.GetData(_sqlStatement)

        _Logger.SendLog(Me.Name & "." & procName & " - Device data fetch completed.", NLog.LogLevel.Trace)

        'Update the display
        Call BuildGrid(_myDataSet, uxGrid)

    Catch ex As Exception

        Beep()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName)
        _Logger.SendLog(ex.Message & ".  Thrown in module " & Me.Name.ToString & "." & procName, NLog.LogLevel.Error, ex)

    Finally

        Call System.GC.Collect()

    End Try

End Sub




Private Sub BuildGrid(ByVal myDataSet As DataSet, ByVal myGrid As DataGridView)

    Dim myTable As New System.Data.DataTable
    Dim myColCount As Integer
    Dim comboBoxCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim readOnlyCellStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle
    Dim textBoxCol As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Dim gridObject As Object = Nothing

    Const procName As String = "BuildGrid"

    readOnlyCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray

    Try

        _Logger.SendLog(Me.Name & "." & procName & " - Building device data grid.", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, Nothing)

        myTable = myDataSet.Tables(0)
        With myGrid

            'Now add the columns to the grid 
            Dim column As System.Data.DataColumn
            For Each column In myDataSet.Tables(0).Columns
                'We dont want to include the changedon and changedby fields in the grid build
                If column.ColumnName.IndexOf("CHANGED") = -1 Then


                    Select Case column.ColumnName
                        Case "DATASOURCEID"
                            gridObject = New Object
                            comboBoxCol = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
                            'First create the comboboxcolumn for the column
                            'Populate combobox
                            PopulateScadaSourceComboBoxCol(comboBoxCol)
                            comboBoxCol.DataPropertyName = "DATASOURCEID"
                            comboBoxCol.HeaderText = "SCADA SOURCE"
                            comboBoxCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
                            comboBoxCol.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing
                            gridObject = comboBoxCol

                        Case "TEXT"
                            textBoxCol = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                            gridObject = textBoxCol
                            'Now add the columns to the grid 
                            gridObject.DataPropertyName = column.ColumnName.ToString
                            gridObject.HeaderText = column.ColumnName.Replace("TEXT", "DEVICE")
                            gridObject.name = column.ColumnName.Replace("TEXT", "DEVICE")
                            gridObject.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells

                        Case "CATEGORY"
                            textBoxCol = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                            gridObject = textBoxCol
                            'Now add the columns to the grid 
                            gridObject.DataPropertyName = column.ColumnName.ToString
                            gridObject.HeaderText = "CATEGORY"
                            gridObject.name = "CATEGORY"
                            gridObject.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells

                        Case "MOUNTING"
                            textBoxCol = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                            gridObject = textBoxCol
                            'Now add the columns to the grid 
                            gridObject.DataPropertyName = column.ColumnName.ToString
                            gridObject.HeaderText = "MOUNTING"
                            gridObject.name = "MOUNTING"
                            gridObject.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells

                        Case "TANALYSIS"
                            comboBoxCol = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
                            'First create the comboboxcolumn for the column
                            'Populate combobox
                            PopulateUnboundComboBox(comboBoxCol, {"Yes", "No"})
                            comboBoxCol.DataPropertyName = "TANALYSIS"
                            comboBoxCol.HeaderText = "TELECONTROL ANALYSIS"
                            comboBoxCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
                            comboBoxCol.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing
                            gridObject = comboBoxCol

                        Case Else
                            textBoxCol = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                            gridObject = textBoxCol
                            'Now add the columns to the grid 
                            gridObject.DataPropertyName = column.ColumnName.ToString
                            gridObject.HeaderText = "ID"
                            gridObject.name = "ID"
                            gridObject.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells

                    End Select

                    'Now add the textbox columns to the grid 
                    'gridObject.DataPropertyName = column.ColumnName.ToString
                    'gridObject.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
                    .Columns.Add(gridObject)
                End If
            Next

            'Set grid default styles/values
            .Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
            .AllowUserToResizeColumns = True
            .AllowUserToResizeRows = True
            .AllowUserToAddRows = True
            .ReadOnly = True
            .AutoResizeRows()
            .ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText

            'Now bind the datatable to the DGV datasource property
            .DataSource = myTable

        End With

        _Logger.SendLog(Me.Name & "." & procName & " - Building of device data grid has been completed.", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, Nothing)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        textBoxCol = Nothing
        comboBoxCol = Nothing
        readOnlyCellStyle = Nothing
        GC.Collect()
    End Try

End Sub

 Private Sub PopulateUnboundComboBox(ByVal comboBoxCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, byval valList() as string)
      comboBoxCol.Name = "TANALYSIS"
      comboBoxCol.DataSource = valList

      comboBoxCol.ValueMember = ???
      comboBoxCol.DisplayMember = ???

 End Sub
```

EDITED//

Ok, I've made some progress and seem to have almost solved my issue.  The one remaining bug is that the column in the DGV is displaying the 'ValueMember' (1 or 0) rather than the 'DisplayMember' (Yes or No).  I've checked the valuemember and displaymember properties in the comboboxcolumn definition and and they appear to be set correctly.  Here is the associated code:

Excerpt from original code posting listed above

```
 ...

 Case "TANALYSIS"
      gridObject = New Object
      comboBoxCol = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
      'First create the comboboxcolumn for the column
      'Populate combobox

      Dim item As New CBOItem
      Dim itemList As New CBOItemList
      item.ValueMember = 0
      item.DisplayMember = "No"
      itemList.Add(item)
      item = New CBOItem
      item.ValueMember = 1
      item.DisplayMember = "Yes"
      itemList.Add(item)

      PopulateComboBox(comboBoxCol, itemList)
      comboBoxCol.DataPropertyName = "TANALYSIS"
      comboBoxCol.HeaderText = "TELECONTROL ANALYSIS"
      comboBoxCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
      comboBoxCol.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing
      gridObject = comboBoxCol
 ...

Private Sub PopulateComboBox(ByRef comboBoxCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, ByVal itemList As CBOItemList)

    Dim tbl As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim row As DataRow

    tbl.Columns.Add("ValueMember")
    tbl.Columns.Add("DisplayMember")
    row = tbl.NewRow
    row.Item("ValueMember") = itemList(0).ValueMember
    row.Item("DisplayMember") = itemList(0).DisplayMember
    tbl.Rows.Add(row)
    row = tbl.NewRow
    row.Item("ValueMember") = itemList(1).ValueMember
    row.Item("DisplayMember") = itemList(1).DisplayMember
    tbl.Rows.Add(row)

    comboBoxCol.ValueMember = tbl.Columns("ValueMember").ToString
    comboBoxCol.DisplayMember = tbl.Columns("DisplayMember").ToString
    comboBoxCol.DataSource = tbl

End Sub
```

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: Is there any reason you chose to make the user open and select from a CBO rather than use a CheckBox?  That said we cant tell you what you did wrong without the code.  (are the other columns bound?)

Comment: I have added the relevant codes to the original post.

Comment: a) you say it is unbound, but in trying to set `DataPropertyName` you are trying to make it a bound column B) A simple Yes/No list/array wont have a ValueMember; you could create a Type for it, even an anon one.. C) Never concat values into SQL D) There is (almost) never a need to invoke GC directly.

Comment: Ok, looks like the terminology I have used with respect to the CBO column and the grid may be incorrect.  So what I am trying to achieve is allow the user to select from a simple Yes/No list and have values 1 and 0 respectively inserted into the underlying datasource of the grid.

Comment: As to the use of the concatentation in the SQL statement, the application has no exposure external to the company, so issues such as SQL injection are not a concern.  In addition the use of standard SQL statements and concatenation is consistent with the rest of the application, so in this situation I felt that consistency of design was more important than best practice.